# Eclipse won't restart

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse

I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers 
Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
When I restarting it it shuts down also fine but don't want to start.

All I have in workspace/.metadata/.log file is:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.browser 2 0 2015-05-14 09:49:26.402
!MESSAGE Internal browser is not available: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-05-14 09:49:29.067
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

This warning isn't repeat with restart trial.

What I need to look for for find the reason?

Comment: There might be some messages in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Comment: Nothing. It writes nothing, just old warning about Git